# How do I make the menu in the center of the block?

Tags: html, css, navbar, center

My question is how do I put the menu in the middle of the header block because I can't figure it out.

I am trying to make a website for my dad's business by using some templates that I find on the internet, this is one of them and I really like but I can't figure out how to center the navbar. I am not the best when it comes to CSS.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}


/* ~~ Top Navigation Bar ~~ */

#navigation-container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
}

.navigation-bar {
  background-color: black;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navigation-bar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation-bar li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">

<head>
  <div class="navigation-bar">
    <div id="navigation-container">
      <img src="images/logo.png">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rent a Boat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please use a [Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/)! Your markup is invalid! The `<link>` tag belongs inside the `<head>` element. Then visual Content is not allowed to be part of the `<head>` element and belongs inside the `<body>` element. `<head>` !== `<header>`. `<head>` is for tags such as `link`, `meta`, `<title>`... Then

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote most parts of your code to fix the invalid markup and to include the correct semantic tags for screenreaders. Also, I changed a bit the structure to be semantically correct. Simplified your CSS.

1. For the invalid Markup, read my comment below your question.
2. Use the `<header>`-tag for your header. It is a semantic tag.
3. The image is part of the header but not part of the navigation, semantically speaking. AS such place it inside the header but not inside the navigation
4. Use the `<nav>`-tag for your navigation bar as it is also a semantic tag.
5. Learn about Flexbox and use it! `float` is a property to float an element within a text block (like in a newspaper). It is not for aligning purposes. Since 2013 we have Flexbox which is well supported since 2015!

**Side Note:** 
I know this sounds hard but it must be said. If the coding is done for a **business** Homepage then no **unexperienced** or **beginner without proper skill/knowledge-base** should attempt to do it. At least not without the supervision of an experienced coder. A Business Homepage is one of the most important marketing aspects. If you screw this up, then the business will be hurt from it and your dad would lose money!

Then even for experienced coders, it is a **NO-GO** to just copy code from the internet and include it without correction or knowing what they include. The coder is responsible for the code and can not just state that he didn't write those code pieces originally. It is a coder's job to correct errors such as invalid markups.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* ~~ Top Navigation Bar ~~ */
header {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  align-items: center; /* vertically center the links */
}

nav {
  margin: 0 auto; /* horizontally center the links */
}

nav > ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50.jpg">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rent a Boat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the tip! This is a test website for my dads business and i have one of my friends who is a experienced in CSS and HTML and he is teaching but the thing was he was asleep because it was about 12pm where I was so I didnt want to wake him up. I found a different header which I made and got CSS help from him. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

- `#navigation-container` set `max-width` instread of `width`.
- `margin:0 auto` will push from left and right side to `#navigation-container` so it will be center.
- I have replace you css with better approach by using `display:flex` and setting `justify-content:center` sets it center to horizontally.
- Ans it's good practice to use `<header></header>` tag for header and include it inside of `<body>` rather than in `<head>`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/* ~~ Top Navigation Bar ~~ */

#navigation-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  /*you just need to set this*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navigation-bar {
  background-color: black;
}

.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.navigation-bar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation-bar li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="navigation-bar">
      <div id="navigation-container">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Rent a Boat</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: you should use semantic tags and correct the semantically incorrect positioning.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you are trying to center the navbar at the top of the page. To the (`.navigation-bar li`) class, add the following property: `display: inline-block;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}

/* ~~ Top Navigation Bar ~~ */

#navigation-container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
}

.navigation-bar {
  background-color: black;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navigation-bar li {
  display: inline-block;    
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation-bar li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: `inline-block` is the completely wrong approach for this IMHO. Also, it does not address all the other issues. And your snippet does not work as you didn't include the HTML

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).